# .Net 3.5 Windows Service hide WCF Service Host

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5, windows-services

I got a Windows service installed on my development machine (that I made) and I want to interact with it. For a reason I don't know, each time I start the client, a WCF Service Host pop and said that the address is already in use ... which is true ... but how can I do to NOT start that Windows ?

Is it because my two projects (server and client) are in the same solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its because they are in the same solution.  Right click on your WCF project > Properties > WCF Options > Uncheck Start "WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution".